# Case-sensitive ids when routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

I'm attempting to implement a vanity URL system in my Rails app. On localhost:3000 server, the implementation was working perfectly. I had a system where a Recipe could be requested by its name, but also could fall back to default behavior if requested by ID. This implementation worked fine for lower and upper case names, regardless of what the name was actually saved as.

For example

`http://localhost:3000/recipes/pizza`

and

`http://localhost:3000/recipes/Pizza`

would lead to the same page, even if the record was saved as "Pizza".

Where as:

`http://www.test-server.com/recipes/pizza`

and

`http://www.test-server.com/recipes/Pizza`

will not bring up the same page.

My question is, why is the capitalization ignored on my localhost server. And also, is there a graceful to take care of this problem for the online implementation?

Here is some relevant code of how I have the vanity URLs implemented at the moment.

```
#models/recipe.rb  
 def to_param
    name.parameterize
  end


# relevant code from routes.rb
  match '/recipes/:name' => 'recipes#show'

# relevant code from controllers/recipe_controller.rb
  def show
    name = params[:id].gsub("-", "\s")
    @recipe = Recipe.find_by_name(name)
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) if @recipe.nil?
    puts @recipe.ingredients.inspect
    puts @recipe.amounts.inspect
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
 end
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.coolnotions.com/Articles/Article_02.htm

Comment: What database servers are you running on each machine?

Comment: Both machines are running MySQL. The test host is hosted on Heroku and I know they may be translating the MySQL to PostreSQL.

Comment: Then that's your problem. PostgreSQL is case sensitive. See my solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How strings get compared is down to the collation used for your columns (which can be set on a per table or per column level if necessary).

MySQL by default uses a [case insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) collation, however if your local database and your production database had different default settings and you didn't specify collation or character sets explicitly then you may have ended up with different collations in production (`show create table foo` can show you what collation a table's columns use)

If you are running on heroku then unless you have gone out of your way to pay for an add-inn that provides a mysql db then you will be using postgres and postgres will be default do case sensitive comparisons. Heroku doesn't do any "translation" by the way, it's just that activerecord knows how to deal with postgres. There is no escaping the sometimes subtle differences between databases, so it is strongly advised that you use the same database locally as the one you will be deploying to.

Answer (score 0):

As Frederick already wrote, your PostgreSQL on Heroku is case-sensitive.

I suggest that you make sure all your searchable keywords in the DB are lowercase (eg: pizza and NOT Pizza). Then you use this little gem to make the routing part of your URL lowercase automatically:

https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

/ Carsten